# In the interval $[0,a]$ randomly are picked $n$ points(uniformly). Find probability density function of $k$-th point abscise.

Tags: probability, measure-theory

In the interval $[0,a]$ randomly are picked $n$ points(uniformly). Find probability density function of $k$-th point abscise.

My work.

So my thinking is first to find cdf and then derivative would be pdf.

So let's say distance between $0$ and $k$-th point is $x$. Then distance from $k$-th point to $a$ will be $a-x.$

So $F(x)=P(X\leq x_k)$(finding probability of having $k-1$ points at the left of $k$-th point) =
$\displaystyle\binom{n-1}{k-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{x}{a}\right)^{n-k}\binom{n}{1}$.

This I got using binomial formula, first we choose that $k$-th point with last binom, with first binom we choose left $k-1$ and last two are just probabilities. When I take derivative of this I get different answer.

Answer in the book is $\displaystyle f(x)=\binom{n-1}{k-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{x}{a}\right)^{n-k}\binom{n}{1}\frac{1}{a}$ if $x \in (0,a)$ and $0,{\rm otherwise}.$

Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You are being asked to find the pdf of the [k-th order statistic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) in an IID sample of length $n$ of $\textrm{Uniform}[0,a]$ random variables. In your case, $F(x)=x/a$ and $f(x)=1/a$ for $x\in [0,a]$.

Comment: But that does not match answer in the book.

Comment: @unit1991 you may simplify the binomial coefficients and obtain the answer